# How to use Kendo UI MVC Extensions with require js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, requirejs, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace KendoMvcApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest req)
        {
            var products = CreateProducts();
            var result = products.ToDataSourceResult(req);
            return Json(result);
        }     

        private static IEnumerable<Product> CreateProducts()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                yield return new Product
                {
                    ProductId = i,
                    ProductName = "Product " + i,
                    ProductPrice = i * 2.5
                };
            }
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a view that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div id="grid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">            
    require.config({
        baseUrl : '@Url.Content("~/Scripts")',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
            'kendo': 'kendo-ui'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: 'jQuery'
            }
        }            
    });           
    require(['jquery', 'kendo/kendo.grid.min'], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#grid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        data: 'Data',
                        total: 'Total',
                        aggregates: 'AggregateResults',
                        model: {
                            id: "ProductId",
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                ProductPrice: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")",
                            dataType: "json",
                            method: "post"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"
                },
                sortable: {
                    mode: "single"
                },
                columns: ["ProductName", "ProductPrice"],
                scrollable: false,
                pageable: true
            });
        });            
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my directory structure is:

- Scripts/kendo-ui/* (all the kendo files, including the mvc one)
- Scripts/require.js
- Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

which *nearly* works except that server-side sorting doesn't get applied.

This is because the **kendo.aspnet.mvc.min.js** file is never downloaded (of course, as require JS doesn't know anything about it) so to remedy that I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div id="grid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts")',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
            'kendo': 'kendo-ui',
            'kendo-mvc': 'kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: 'jQuery'
            }
        }
    });
    require(['jquery', 'kendo-mvc', 'kendo/kendo.grid.min'], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#grid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        data: 'Data',
                        total: 'Total',
                        aggregates: 'AggregateResults',
                        model: {
                            id: "ProductId",
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                ProductPrice: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")",
                            dataType: "json",
                            method: "post"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"
                },
                sortable: {
                    mode: "single"
                },
                columns: ["ProductName", "ProductPrice"],
                scrollable: false,
                pageable: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But that produced this error:

[image: split configuration error]

And attempted to load the js files thus:

[image: try 1 files]

The red spots are 404 not found as it is looking for the js files in a folder called kendo under the scripts folder.

So then I thought I would try including the all version instead so I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div id="grid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts")',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
            'kendo': 'kendo-ui/kendo.all.min',
            'kendo-mvc': 'kendo-ui/kendo.aspnetmvc.min'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: 'jQuery'
            }
        }
    });
    require(['jquery', 'kendo', 'kendo-mvc'], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#grid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        data: 'Data',
                        total: 'Total',
                        aggregates: 'AggregateResults',
                        model: {
                            id: "ProductId",
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                ProductPrice: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")",
                            dataType: "json",
                            method: "post"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"
                },
                sortable: {
                    mode: "single"
                },
                columns: ["ProductName", "ProductPrice"],
                scrollable: false,
                pageable: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But that produced these errors:

[image: ASP NET MVC Errors]

And attempted to load the js files thus:

[image: case 2 files]

In this case - the red spots are 404 not found as it is looking for the files directly under the Scripts folder.

So here is my question:

> > How can I include said file in a require JS type scenario?

Aside:  *I would like to be using the kendo.all.min file and not the separate ones as I want to use knockout-kendo in the future and that seems to not work with the separate file but if the only way to make this work is to use the separate file approach, that is fine.*

Comment: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/introduction

Comment: What order are the script files loaded in the network view (Chrome developer tools, Firebug)?

Comment: @Chris - I've added the network order - the red spots indicate 404 not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a while to get your code working but after having been fiddling around with it a little I managed to get the sorting to work with just a tiny little change in your original code.

The only thing I changes was on the require line where I added the mvc file as well. Then all the paths became correct and it all worked out fine.

```
['jquery', 'kendo/kendo.grid.min', 'kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min']
```

In my code I've used "Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2013" with the `jQuery.min.js` file that was included in that package. The complete View code then becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
  require.config({
    baseUrl : '@Url.Content("~/Scripts")',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
        'kendo': 'kendo-ui'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        }
    }            
  });           
  require(['jquery', 'kendo/kendo.grid.min', 'kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                schema: {
                    data: 'Data',
                    total: 'Total',
                    aggregates: 'AggregateResults',
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductId",
                        fields: {
                            ProductName: { type: "string" },
                            ProductPrice: { type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")",
                        dataType: "json",
                        method: "post"
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"
            },
            sortable: {
                mode: "single"
            },
            columns: ["ProductName", "ProductPrice"],
            scrollable: false,
            pageable: true
        });
    });            
  });
</script>
```

I hope it'll work in your code as well.

Comment: Thanks - putting in this code I get two javascript errors: script error for jquery and reference error: jQuery not defined

Comment: That's because the jQuery I was using was in a file named `jquery.min.js`. Please change that row in my example to the name of your jquery file. I should have been more clear on that one. I'll update my example as well so it has the same jQuery file name as yours.

Comment: I also have the jquery.min file that comes with kendo

Comment: Well, use your original code and ignore mine. Then just add 'kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min' on the require row...

Comment: If my answer is working for you then please mark my answer as correct also :) Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Let's try building up from a minimal working version. You said you have the following in the directory:

- Scripts/kendo-ui/* (all the kendo files, including the mvc one)
- Scripts/require.js
- Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

To get that to load all the dependencies, you might try something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts")',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
            'kendo': 'kendo-ui/kendo.all.min',
            'kendo-mvc': 'kendo-ui/kendo.aspnetmvc.min'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: 'jQuery'
            },
            'kendo-mvc' : {
                deps: ['kendo'] //kendo needs to be loaded before kendo-mvc?
            }
        }
    });
    require(['jquery', 'kendo', 'kendo-mvc'], function ($) {
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I played around with putting it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUnpE/2/), but ran into a number of problems (Kendo actually requires jQuery 1.9.0, etc.) that you can probably resolve on your own.

The key seems to be that your last version is loading kendo.data, kendo.combobox, and a bunch of other files that aren't referenced anywhere. Figuring out where those requests came from would help solve this mystery.

**Update**:
Here's one possibility. If kendo-mvc is loading dependencies like this:

```
["./kendo.data.min","./kendo.combobox.min","./kendo.multiselect.min","./kendo.‌​validator.min"]
```

Then it may fail because RequireJS looks for dependencies relative to the name of the module, which has been aliased as kendo-mvc. Let's try not renaming it (see below), and see if that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts")',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',
            'kendo-ui/kendo': 'kendo-ui/kendo.all.min',
            'kendo-ui/kendo-mvc': 'kendo-ui/kendo.aspnetmvc.min'
        },
...
    require(['jquery', 'kendo-ui/kendo', 'kendo-ui/kendo-mvc'], function ($) {
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Using your approach I still get 404 not found forr kendo.data.min, combobox, multiselect and validator (same as in the second attempt in the question).  It is looking for all 4 files directly under the Scripts directory.  I opened up the kendo.aspnetmvc.min file and can see this bit '(["./kendo.data.min","./kendo.combobox.min","./kendo.multiselect.min","./kendo.validator.min"],function(){' which looks like the define that specifies these dependencies.  That's a bit confusing for me as the files are in the same directory as kendo.aspnetmvc.min  so ./ would be able to find them :-S.

Comment: Anyhoo, is it possible, therefore, to configure it somehow such that ./xxx would be pointing under kendo-ui?

Comment: Try adding kendo.data.min etc. to paths in require.config. Where are those files located right now, kendo-ui? Also, can you share the copies of these files that you're using?

Comment: OK, I'll try.  You can download all the kendo stuff from here:  https://www.kendoui.com/download/download-kendo.aspx?pid=KENDOUIMVC&lict=1 - it is a 30 day trial license thing.

Comment: oh, yes - all those files are located in the kendo-ui folder right now

Comment: If you add a dependency between kendo-mvc and kendo shouldn't you only require kendo-mvc ? I think it should pull down kendo first anyway. This is actually what I'm trying to achieve but i keep getting `Error: The kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js script is not included.` anyway.